# Send Mail Async In Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have this code

```
protected void ASPxButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

    mail.From = new MailAddress("paragonadmin@qss.co.za", "Paragon Admin");
    mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("dewald@qss.co.za", "Appointment Scheduled"));
    mail.Subject = "Enter mail subject";
    mail.Body = "Enter mail body";

    SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.qss.co.za");
    smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("paragonadmin@qss.co.za", "123456");
    Object state = mail;

    //event handler for asynchronous call
    smtpClient.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(smtpClient_SendCompleted);
    try
    {
        //smtpClient.Send(mail);
        smtpClient.SendAsync(mail, state);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { /* exception handling code here */ }
}

void smtpClient_SendCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MailMessage mail = e.UserState as MailMessage;

    if (!e.Cancelled && e.Error != null)
    {
        ASPxLabel1.Text = "Mail sent successfully";
    }
}
```

It is supposed to send a mail asynchronous in my application, but for some reason I get a "Failure sending mail" error message.

Any advice

Comment: what about `smtpClient.Send(mail)`? Even that's giving error??

Comment: It might be because your IP is restricted to relay information to your indicated SMTP server.

Comment: What do you mean by "your IP is restricted to relay information to your indicated SMTP server"